# Requirement of Client certificates in PostgreSQL SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openssl, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.6

I am new to DBA role and setting up SSL for the first time. I have created a key and generated a certificate for testing using openssl with the help of [this article](https://jelastic.com/blog/establish-secure-ssl-connection-to-postgresql-database-server/). This article says to generate key and certificate for client also. i have generated that and tested for an on premises server.

we have a test aws rds instance and i have downloaded a certificate for RDS provided at this [link](https://ankane.org/postgres-sslmode-explained). and i am able to connect to rds instance without using any client key/certificate using below command.

```
psql -h somehost.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432     "dbname=test user=testuser sslrootcert=rds-ca-2019-root.pem sslmode=verify-full"
```

however, if i dont specify sslrootcert then i get below error

```
psql: root certificate file "/root/.postgresql/root.crt" does not exist
Either provide the file or change sslmode to disable server certificate verification.
```

i want to know why i didn't need a client key and certificate in case of AWS?

If we use certificate signed by a Certificate authority, we wont be needing client key 
and secret?

what i have to do extra to enable SSL in production if we want a single certificate for all clients?

**I want to use sslmode=verify-full**

Comment: Do you want the client to verify the server certificate or do you want the server to authenticate the client using a client certificate, or do you want both?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : server certificate verification will do the job for me. As we may have many clients with read some level of read access, we dont want client certificate verification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't trust random articles, consult [the official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html).

As you have found, you need to use the connection string option `sslmode=verify-full` (or set the environment variable [`PGSSLMODE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.21.3.4.12.1.1) to `verify-full`) to verify the server certificate.

For that, you do not need client certificates. All you need is the certification authority (CA) certificate on the client, so that the client can verify that the server certificate was signed with that certificate.

Client certificates are only needed if you want the server to authenticate the client using certificates.

If you don't specify the CA certificate's path with either the [`sslrootcert`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-SSLROOTCERT) connection string option or the [`PGSSLROOTCERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.21.3.4.17.1.1) environment variable, the client will search the CA certificate in `~/.postgresql/root.crt`, as detailed in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html#LIBQ-SSL-CERTIFICATES).

Comment: Even if we don't specify sslmode=verify-full, Postgres allow you to connect. How we can tune pg_hba.conf such that it will force client to use CA cert always. I did not find such setting.

Comment: @NirajNandane Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Client certs are optional, and as far as I know are much rarer than server certs.  You can demand a client cert by setting the authentication method to `cert` in pg_hba.conf, or by adding the `clientcert` option to some other authentication method.  If you don't do either of those, then client certs are not used.

Comment: I want to use sslmode=verify-full , can this be done without clientcert?

Comment: Yes.  In the example you give, you are already verifying the server cert (or erroring out in the 2nd example because it can't be done), but not using a client cert.